# Reference book for functions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, reference-request

I need to study (work on problems) about these type of real functions for my exam:

**polynomials**- remainder theorem, factor theorem

**rational functions**

**exponential function**

**logarithmic functions**

There are college algebra books that cover these subjects, but they don't have hard, interesting problems.

If you know any book that have **advanced problems** please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: Did you search **here** ? You should find very interesting, not so easy, problems.

Comment: Maybe look at the problems in G. H. Hardy's [**A Course of Pure Mathematics**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0521092272), skipping stuff that requires calculus.

Comment: If you are primarily interested in solving problems, check the [Art of Problem Solving](https://artofproblemsolving.com/) website.